# Multiple Endpoints in same controller with different parameter

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, url-routing

Been years since I had to do this and the heat must be getting to me!

I have my home controller:

```
    public ActionResult Index(string param1, string param2, string param3)
    {
        return View();
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

I have 1 Index.cshtml page.

In my startup,cs:

```
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}");

            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default2",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{param1}/{param2}/{param3}");
        });
```

The error I get is:

**{"error":"APP: The request matched multiple endpoints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this,

```
using System;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Routing;

namespace RouteTemplateProvider.Controllers
{
    public class RouteWithParamAttribute : Attribute, IRouteTemplateProvider
    {
        public string Template => "{param1}/{param2}/{param3}";
        public int? Order { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
    {
        [RouteWithParam]
        public string Index(string param1, string param2, string param3)
        {
            return "Index with param";
        }

        public string Index()
        {
            return "Index no param";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    // hits when navigating to https://localhost:5001/one/two/three
    [HttpGet("{param1}/{param2}/{param3}")]
    public IActionResult Index(string param1, string param2, string param3)
    {
        return View();
    }

    // hits when navigating to https://localhost:5001/
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

and in Startup#Configure

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
  endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

Comment: Thanks I had tried that but it was never invoked. I managed to find a different way of accomplishing what I want. I left the question up as was curious whether there was a simple solution. Thank you

Comment: OK, please feel free to share your solution with the community. This is pretty simple stuff, hence the fix should also be simple.

Comment: Yes it should be a simple solution but I could not find one. My own solution was not to use this approach and do something else. Hence why I have not answered my own question because as I said previously I did something else. Your seemed sure your own answer was right? I assumed you tested it? Perhaps give a fuller answer so we the community can verify your answer? Thanks

Comment: Will do, and I will start with replacing app.UseEndpoints with a standard one that contains a single entry. I believe the dog is buried in that place. I did'nt see that config right away, sorry for that.

Comment: Good thinking :) I did think that too but I am also using signalR and the recommendation is to use endpoints fir it. Plus it is a very hot day lol. I look forward to your answer. It could a popular viewed answer if u solve it. Have a nice evening

Comment: Tested on my machine. Have a nice evening :-)

Comment: Can you do the same as I did; use a fresh project and apply my code just to make sure you don't have any other settings that clutters up?

Comment: sorry for the delay on my response,  Just sooo busy. I am sure it is an error on my part and not yours.  The other answer worked straight away though I would have preferred the 'neatness' of yours.  Sorry i could not evaluate properly.  Just time pressure and the fact the other answer worked.. Thanks again,  Gave you +1. Just wish I got accept more than 1 answer